# Does Sails.js or Meteor.js work with ArangoDB or OrientDB?

Tags: meteor, sails.js, orientdb, arangodb, allegrograph

I'm planning to work on a social site and I would like to leverage both a document and graph database for all of the desired features. Is there a way to get Meteor.js or Sail.js (or any better) to work with ArangoDB or OrientDB? Or should I just stick with the bundled MongoDB and integrate something like allegrograph DB?

Answer (score 4):

Sails.js has support for both of the databases you mention:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-orientdb
- https://github.com/rosmo/sails-arangodb

In addition to MongoDB, Postgres, and dozens of others.

Comment: we now have a sample app howto use sails with arangodb: https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/UsingArangoDBWithSailsJS.html Plus sails-arangodb now available via npm

Answer (score 2):

Sails.js is a classic mvc client-server web application framwork, basically its ruby on rails implemented for node.js + webscockets, so mostly all you need to make it work with any backend database is make changes to the orm.

Meteor is a very different beast, it is a very opinionated realtime end to end web framework including client server and database, by behing very very opinionated it solves many of the common issues in realtime application, where you need to implement a mechanisms for very quickly updating all your clients of each others actions and take care of things like latency compensation, data collision resolution, and real time client version managment, This is implemented by using web sockets and the mongoDB's write ahead logging for triggres of data updates, making meteor somewhat coupled with mongo.

But you can make orientdb work pretty well with meteor using the new orientDB live query api. It is a pubsub implementation for query results, and can be used for efficent updates pushed from the db through the server directly to the client with very little overhead on the server. This is far from production ready and only currently works on the orient db 2.1 rc5 version.

I have implemented a small meteor demo application as an example https://github.com/imdark/meteor-orientdb-demo

Answer (score 1):

Please check on [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Alternative_Databases) the Alternative Database Post, they mention **neo4j-livedata** and **minineo4j**.

Here is the [Atmosphere package: ostrio:neo4jdriver](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/neo4jdriver)

Is there a specific economic or technological reason why you *consider* not to use the very well integrated mongoDB as the database of choice?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The social data we will need to work with heavily will be on around bidirectional, 3 level deep relationships across, that will include inferred relationships. With that in mind we were strongly leaning towards ArangoDB to leverage JavaScript in the DB queries. Based on what we know at the moment we would need a document DB, but we would also need a Graph DB, do finding a multi Domain NoSql DB was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Travis answer I also recommend [waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb) for Sails.js.