# Does Meteor.js work with ArangoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, arangodb

The answers to [Does Sails.js or Meteor.js work with ArangoDB or OrientDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789100/does-sails-js-or-meteor-js-work-with-arangodb-or-orientdb) do not contain info specifically about Meteor/Arangodb combination.

This is what I need to know: how close is ArangoDB to state of being a drop-in replacement for Mongo in Meteor?

The reasons I would prefer to use Arango:

- friendlier license (Apache vs Mongo's AGPL)
- graph db features built-in (I'm going to need that)
- ACID transactions

Comment: I think that you probably want to take a look at appolo:
https://github.com/apollostack/apollo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Meteor only supports MongoDB directly, so there is no real "drop-in" alternative to MongoDB if you are a bleeding heart Meteor developer.

Because the Meteor server is built on top of Node.js you can simply use the [JavaScript driver for ArangoDB](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) to talk to ArangoDB from your server-side Meteor code. Alternatively you can simply use the [ArangoDB HTTP API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3/HTTP/) directly.

For a less database-specific solution you can look into [Apollo](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo) as BennyB pointed out, but keep in mind that Apollo communicates using GraphQL, which while offering a lot of flexibility to frontend development also creates certain limitations for backend development, especially when it comes to optimizing queries for performance. A naive implementation of a GraphQL schema treats the database purely as a key-value storage, which will not play into the strengths you're interested in (specifically transactions won't be available this way).